# Binding ng-model dynamically with sub-fields

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to write a piece of code where I need to bind ng-model with dynamic value and static sub-fields.
eg: 
html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="map[type]['name']"/>
```

js:

```
$scope.map = {};
$scope.type = "A";
```

desired output:

```
{
"map": {
    "A": {
        "name": "something"
    }
}
}
```

I know that ng-model="map[type]" would work but i want to add one more field for binding.
Could you please help with this?

Comment: Have you tried giving it a model name of ng-model="map.type.name" ?

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work. (https://plnkr.co/edit/6G6AkPClpDrJdxtcKTnM?p=preview)

Comment: @AJRichardson I do not want the 'name' attribute to be predefined. I want the data to be two-way bound to name attribute inside 'A'. I have number of fields on the html which are children of type attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It just works. See updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6G6AkPClpDrJdxtcKTnM?p=preview).

Here is my code. If you don't want `name` to be pre-defined, then make sure it isn't in quotes.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.map = {};
  $scope.type = "A";
  $scope.property = "name";
});
```

And the html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="map[type][property]"/>
```

Note that when you type in the input, the name is updated.